# Not sure about php mail configuration

Tags: php, email

I was reading the php `mail()` function doc but I missed some config fields such as `user` or `passsword`.

I know the smtp server is set on `php.ini`, but I haven't seen anything to set the `user` and the `password`.

How can I set the user which I want to send the email to as sender?

Comment: this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18185233/9267467) will help you to do it. good luck :D

Comment: I'm not using xampp

Comment: You could also try https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you only need to set up the user and pass, this script will help you. it's work fine

```
SMTP = smtp.example.com
smtp_port = 25
username = info@example.com
password = yourmailpassord
sendmail_from = info@example.com
```

Comment: But in the `mail()` doc on php docs ,dosen't  use password ,Hou can it be this way? [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: yes, you should apply that script in your `php.ini`

Comment: please update your question that where your app running.  so the other users can give you the perpect answer, :D